# How to check in JavaScript if XMLHttpRequest object supports W3C Progress Events?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

Is there any way to check within JavaScript if `XMLHttpRequest` object supports [W3C Progress Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/)?  I mean here if setting `onload`, `onprogress`, `onabort`, `onerror`, etc. properties to some handler function would have those function called those events, as described.

Additional (bonus) question: is there a way to augment `XMLHttpRequest` (e.g. using some timers) to support those events?

*Sidenote: I have first found about W3C Progress Events in the context of `XMLHttpRequest` [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/09/firefox-35firebug-xmlhttprequest-and-readystatechange-bug/)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried doing it this way?

```
try {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if ('onprogress' in xhr) {
        // Browser supports W3C Progress Events
    } else {
        // Browser does not support W3C Progress Events
    }
} catch (e) {
    // Browser is IE6 or 7
}
```

I tested this in Firefox & IE8. Firefox shows it supports it. IE says it has no support for W3C Progress events.

Comment: Alternative to `if (xhr.onload !== undefined) { ... }` is to use `if ('onload' in xhr) { ... }`

Comment: it's better to test for 'onprogress' in xhr, because some browsers (Opera) implements onload/onerror, but not onprogress, although Opera doens't fires onprogress, but it can be emulated with: setInterval( { if (xhr.readyState === 3 && xhr.responseText !== last) xhr.onprogress(); }, 250);

Comment: @4esn0k I've updated my answer. I wasn't aware that Opera had a different implementation. Thanks.