# How can I use Modernizr to test a browser for AJAX support?

Tags: ajax, jquery, modernizr, progressive-enhancement

As a big fan of Progressive-Enhancement, I use Modernizr to test browser capabilities. **How can I use Modernizr to test the browser's support of AJAX** (specifically, jQuery's AJAX functions)?

Comment: Because a Google search on the topic is a dead-end, I wonder if AJAX is automatically supported with JavaScript support, so there's no *need* to test for it.

Comment: Are there still browsers around that don't support AJAX? The only one that comes to mind is IE5 or IE6...

Comment: Modernizr is a library for detecting browser capabilities. jQuery is not a browser capability — you either have it available (if you have loaded it), or you don't; its availability does not depend on the browser but on you. jQuery itself claims IE6.0+ compatibility, so it it a safe bet to assume that if you have jQuery loaded, you can use its AJAX methods.

Comment: @Pekka Older mobile devices that have browsers may not support ajax, see jQuery Mobile's device support list.

Comment: Does it have to be a Modernizr test for support? If not, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249502/how-to-check-in-javascript-if-xmlhttprequest-object-supports-w3c-progress-events

Comment: @lanzz: agreed, Modernizr is a library and jQuery is not a browser capability. I'd like to use Modernizr to test for the browser's capability to implement AJAX. Specifically jQuery's AJAX, but that's just a detail. I don't think it *is* safe to assume that jQuery load means you can use AJAX. In fact, I bet you cannot assume that, which is why jQuery has jQuery.support.ajax, n'est pas?

Comment: Why do you insist on using only Modernizr and nothing else for detecting something that Modernizr does not support detection of? You should rely on `jQuery.support.ajax` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth, I have added issue #734 to Modernizr to add a test for AJAX, [developed the test](https://github.com/jhfrench/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/ajax.js), created a [JSFiddle to test, er, the test](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/t4DHx/)...and [initiated a pull-request (issue #735)](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/735) back to the fine folks who maintain Modernizr.

The relevant JS:

```
Modernizr.addTest('ajax', function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    return !!('onreadystatechange' in xhr);
});
```

Comment: Kevin's answer is also very useful, but the above code is how to test for AJAX support through Modernizr.

Comment: Is this still the best way to check for jQuery AJAX with modernizr, or has anything changed in the past 4 years?

Comment: @Adam If you want to know specifically about jQuery's AJAX compatability, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12961373/1430996

Answer (score 9):

You don't need Modernizer to test this, jQuery has it built-in.

```
if (jQuery.support.ajax) {
    alert("Ajax is supported!");
}
```

Although i'm not sure exactly how jQuery handles `$.ajax` calls when it isn't supported. It will either fail silently, or trigger the error callback. If it's important to you, you should test it.

Comment: Good lead. I now see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/, which curiously references Modernizr: "For your own project's feature-detection needs, we strongly recommend the use of an external library such as Modernizr instead of dependency on properties in jQuery.support."

Comment: With that in mind, you can expect this test to no longer exist in jQuery 2.0, but it should continue to exist in jQuery 1.9 (oldIE support version)

Comment: Right; this doesn't make your answer wrong. I'll just leave the question open a little longer to attract more comments.

Comment: One thing's for sure though, modernizr doesn't have a test for ajax. You could use the one jQuery uses if you're worried about it disappearing from the jQuery core. Although, i'm having a hard time finding it in the source.

Comment: So a test that results in a Modernizr-styled class append to HTML tag (nod to j08691):
    try {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        if ('onprogress' in xhr) {
            $('html').addClass('ajax');
        }
    }
    catch (exception) {
       console.log(exception.message);
    }

Answer (score 1):

may be or may not be relevant to the question but you can use the exception handling of jquery ajax. To answer the question of Kevin B. without any exception handling it will just fail silently (the callback will just return nothing). So if you want it to show anything use exception handling.

Short example:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_page.php",
success: function(data, status, xhr) {
// perform operations on success
alert('Success');
},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
// perform operations on error
alert(xhr.responseText);
}
});
```

Comment: A good thought, but I'd rather test for AJAX once, then adjust the DOM/interactions. Your idea would try any/all AJAX and handle. I'm a novice at progressive-enhancement, but I think this conflict ("test, then layer on enhancements" vs "try, then accomodate failuer") is where progressive-enhancement and graceful degradation fundamentally differ.