# Ajax How to get Multiple Response while response is generating

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to know if it's possible to get print something while Ajax is processing the Request.If yes then please let me know, Because i am facing one problem and i want to get to print something in between Ajax call request and it's response comes

actually i want to read csv of 3000+ rows and in between this process i want to display no of rows read and copied in another csv.

so i want to show something like process bar that out of 3000 there are 50 rows copies completely and this will continue process until it will reach to 3000 rows.

it there a way then let me know!

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: ok i add some more detail information so is it ok! or let me know if more information requires.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XHR progress events (if your browser supports them):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/progress/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#interface-progressevent

[How to check in JavaScript if XMLHttpRequest object supports W3C Progress Events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249502/how-to-check-in-javascript-if-xmlhttprequest-object-supports-w3c-progress-events)

But your question is more than simply *I have 1000 bytes out of a possible 9999*. You want to know exactly how many rows you have read up to that point.

I think you can read `xhr.responseText` on each progress event, but only if the request is parseable when incomplete (such as plain text), and also when not using an async request - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5319647/319878.

But for libraries like [`zip.js`](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) that use non-text binary data with `arraybuffer`s when requesting zip content, this will not work, as these requests must be async (http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsetype-attribute). If you try to use `xhr.responseText` in this case, you will get an error like this (example from Firefox):

```
[Exception... "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"
code: "11"
nsresult: "0x8053000b (InvalidStateError)"
location: "http://localhost/xhr-progress-test/test-xhr-on-progress.html Line: 1075"]
```

So for zipped content (using `zip.js`) I think you would have to wait for all of the response to arrive before using it. This is not what you want.

Much simpler would be to modify your server code to return a selection of rows at a time. E.g. rows 1-100, then 101-200, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may try one of multiple approaches to solve this problem:

- **JSONP Callback**:
  This is an apt solution for your problem. You may batch size your response to 50 rows of CSV data. Each JSONP call will have a start and will get 50 rows of data. So, to fetch 300 rows of data you'll have 6 callbacks. You may pass a start parameter and return start - start+49 rows (total 50) and when start == 1 you may pass the header too. On each successful callback you may increase the progress bar by a proportionate value.

  1. **Pros**: Easy to show progress on no. of rows.
  2. **Cons**: Data to return in the response has to be in JSON format; Need to implement callback function.
- **Calculating bytes**:
  Showing progress on no. of bytes transferred. One example is available on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11265984/1654121). Not sure if it would apply in your case because you want to show progress on the basis of no. of rows.

  1. **Pros**: Easy to show progress on no. of bytes.
  2. **Cons**: May not apply in your case.
- **Loading icon or bar**:
  This is the easiest approach of all. Just show a loading image or a continuous progress bar which keeps on repeating.

  1. **Pros**: Easy to show continuous progress.
  2. **Cons**: Just shows the user that something is happening, nothing on percentage basis.

There could be other solutions too based on your situation, so please take this as a starting point and explore further.